# specify max log json file size in docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to specify the max file size for `json-file` in `docker-compose.yml`, like this,

```
log-opt:
  max-size=50m
```

but when I tried to `docker-compose up`, it threw me an error,

> ERROR: In file './docker-compose.yml', service 'log-opt' must be a mapping not a string.

How to fix it?

ps. I am using `docker 1.11.2`

Answer (score 78):

Your yaml syntax isn't quite correct. The documentation says it should be `options` not `log-opt` (https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#logging). Try this?

```
services:
    service_name:        
        logging:
            driver: "json-file"
            options:
                max-size: "50m"
```

You should define logging section in each one of your services not directly in root of docker-compose.

Comment: Hi, tried that and got a different error, `ERROR: In file './docker-compose.yml', service 'options' must be a mapping not an array.`

Comment: got an error, `ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
Unsupported config option for options: 'max-size'
`

Comment: Are you using docker-compose version 2? Did you set the driver to json-file? I've updated my example to be more complete.

Comment: I am using `docker 1.11.2`, I have updated the op. I think `json-file` is the default `logging driver`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121538/discussion-between-matthew-and-daiyue).

Comment: For a running container, after editing compose file, recreate the container:
`docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d --force-recreate $SVCNAME`

Comment: you want to also limit the file count - https://stackoverflow.com/a/58571932

Comment: Up to date docs reference for these parameters: https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/json-file/

Answer (score 17):

`max-size` store log files until they reach a max-size of VALUE (eg: "2048m").

Example docker-compose file config with max-size.

```
version: '3.2'
services:
  logstash:
    image: docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:7.8.0
    command:  --config.reload.automatic  
    user: savio:savio
    restart: unless-stopped
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-size: "2048m"
    ports:
      - "9600:9600"
```

If you are making a change for an already running container, you need to stop and remove the container and start again.

check log settings

```
]# docker container inspect -f '{{.HostConfig.LogConfig}}' <ContainerName>
```

For more detail: [link](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#logging)

Comment: Specifically, you need to ensure you rebuild the container.

Comment: you want to also limit the file count - https://stackoverflow.com/a/58571932

Comment: What will happen if we reach the max-size limit for log file?