# Is there a way to specify file size limit for docker logs on Google Container Optimized OS?

Tags: google-container-os

I had a very long running (and verbose) container job on Google's Container-Optimized OS (COS) that eventually generated enough logs to fill the disk.

To my knowledge there isn't a way to rotate / limit log file size while using COS.

Inspecting the running container, it appears that it writes an ever-growing file to `/var/lib/docker/containers/` (mounted on the stateful partition) and that `HostConfig.LogConfig.Config` is empty.

I ended up having to SSH in and manually delete the multi-gigabyte log file to make the VM operational again.

I read through https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/containers/configuring-options-to-run-containers and as far as I can tell there isn't a way to (say) pass `--log-opt max-size=XX` as per the Docker documentation:
https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/json-file/

Is there some way to pass that flag? Failing that, are there recommendations on how to rotate logs / limit log size / avoid hitting this problem?

Answer (score 17):

Currently there isn't any way to pass that flag directly to your container.
That being said there is a workaround that might work for you.

It requires you to set the flag globally in /etc/docker/daemon.json
It will then apply to all containers started on that VM. You can do that with a startup script, by using this fragment:

```
cat <<EOF > /etc/docker/daemon.json
{
  "live-restore": true,
  "storage-driver": "overlay2",
  "log-opts": {
    "max-size": "10m"
  }
}
EOF
systemctl restart docker
```

See https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript#providing_startup_script_contents_directly for instructions on startup scripts.
Please refer to docker's documentation on the "log-opts" flag: https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/json-file/#usage

Answer (score 14):

You can limit the logs file size for each service in `docker-compose.yml`.

Just need to add these lines:

```yaml
services:
  app:
    container_name: app
    image: node
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./app:/home/node/app
    working_dir: /home/node/app
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    networks:
      - main
    command: "npm start" 
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-file: "5"   # number of files or file count
        max-size: "10m" # file size

  db:
    ...
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-file: "3"   # number of files or file count
        max-size: "10m" # file size
```

Comment: Google's Container-Optimized OS (COS) doesn't run docker-compose

Comment: Reference for these parameters: https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/json-file/

Answer (score 2):

Container logs by default are not configured to be rotated or limited to a max size by docker. A log file can grow so large that it fills up the disk space if the container runs for long enough and generate enough logs.

See [Docker Logging Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/configure/) for more information on what can be set.

To set log limits for containers on a host --log-opt can be configured with max-size and max-file so that a containers logs are rolled over when they reach a max limit and only a certain number of files are saved before being discarded.

```
# cat /etc/sysconfig/docker 
  OPTIONS='--insecure-registry=172.30.0.0/16 --selinux-enabled --log-opt max size=50m --log-opt max-file=5'
```

Restart docker service for the changes to take effect.

```
# systemctl restart docker
```

If there is already a log file already present on the host that needs to be removed, run the following to clear its contents and reduce its size.

```
# cat /dev/null > /var/lib/docker/containers/CONTAINER_ID/CONTAINER_ID-json.log
```

OR

```
# cat /dev/null >  $(docker inspect --format='{{.LogPath}}'  CONTAINER_ID)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Adding the --log-opt options in /etc/sysconfig/docker file, log rotation  working for new containers, but existing containers its not working . wondering any update option  to exisiting containers ,without recreating the containers ?